# Get the values from CSV based on headers

Tags: c#, csv

I have a csv file with this data

```
Price,volume,"Local, Zones 1 & 2",Zone 3,Zone 4,Zone 5,Zone 6,Zone 7,Zone 8,Zone 9
1,0.1,4.58,4.65,4.74,4.99,5.23,5.47,5.82,6.98
2,0.2,4.99,5.12,5.28,5.5,5.7,5.91,6.3,7.56
3,0.3,5.22,5.61,6.12,7.64,8.39,9.09,9.96,11.94
4,0.4,5.4,6.31,7.24,9.13,10.73,11.77,13.26,15.91
5,0.5,6.18,7.21,8.35,11.5,13.41,14.82,16.97,20.36
```

Now i want to retrieve the values based on volume and zone.if volume is 0.1 and zone is 1,then i should get the value of 4.58.similarly if the volume is 0.5 and xone is 2,then the value should be 6.18.

How can i do this in c#?

Comment: Checkout the [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) library, it rocks for things like this!

Comment: There are good .NET libraries for reading CSV files that support this behavior.  I don't remember the name of the one I've used in the past, but a little googling should get you something.

Comment: I believe this is the one I've used: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Comment: Is the price column telling you the 'zone'? If so then just use it as an index to the set of price columns. You could do it in linq or a switch statement.

Comment: I second the use of FileHelpers.

Comment: I am a beginner in c#.I dont know the concept of FileHelpers.Can anyone help me how can i do that through FileHelpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at "LinqToExcel" if I were you. Then you could do this:

```
var csv = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(csvFile);

var query =
    from row in csv.Worksheet()
    let Volume = row["volume"].Cast<double>()
    where Volume == 0.1
    select new
    {
        Price = row["Price"].Cast<int>(),
        Volume,
        Local = row["Local, Zones 1 & 2"].Cast<decimal>(),
        Zone3 = row["Zone 3"].Cast<decimal>(),
        //etc
    };
```

Comment: can u please tell me which namespace i have to add for LinqToExcel.

Comment: @sindhujampani - You need to add it via NuGet. Do a search in NuGet for "LinqToExcel".

Comment: are NuGet and NuGet.core  same?

Comment: @sindhujampani - I don't know what "NuGet.core" is. I'm talking about when you right-click a project in Visual Studio you get the "Manage NuGet Packages..." menu item. Then in that dialog search for "LinqToExcel".

Answer (score 3):

Dummy way, given that format of file is not going to change and csv file is valid.

```
int zone = 1;
double value = 0.1;

int zoneColumnIndex = Math.Max(zone, 2);
string valueString = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = File.ReadLines("sample.txt")
                    .Skip(1)
                    .Select(s => s.Split(','))
                    .Where(t => t[1] == valueString)
                    .Select(t => t[zoneColumnIndex])
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

To to get the values into a an array or a list

```
 var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.csv"));
    List<string> listA = new List<string>();
    int i = 0;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(',');

        listA.Add(values[i]);
        i += 1;
    }
```

now use your list to itterate through

```
foreach(int j in listA)
{
try
{/* do stuff */}
catch
{/* if your csv cotains strings it wall fall in here */}
}
```